# The GnuCash bug tracker has moved. How do we fix all the Launchpad references still pointing az the old site?

Tags: launchpad, gnucash

The Bug tracker of the GnuCash project has moved:

https://gnucash.org/news.phtml

(news posted on 2018-06-28)

Consequences:

1. The [GnuCash projects bug tracker link on Launchpad](http://ttps://bugs.launchpad.net/gnucash) should be fixed to point to the new tracker.
2. Upstream bug tracker links to the old tracker were recently set to "Expired". The referenced upstream bugs still exists, it's just that they now live in the new tracker, so the links should probably be fixed too. [Example: Bug 1553662.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnucash/+bug/1553662)

I posted [a question with generally the same content as above to the "Launchpad itself" project maintainers](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/670587). It didn't get any reactions for 15 days, so the Launcpad Janitor simply expired it yesterday.

Any idea on what the next step should be?

(Becoming the maintainer of the GnuCash project on Launchpad is not really an option for me.)

Comment: Please write your findings in launchpad, not here.

Comment: @N0rbert As I stated in the question, I did previously tried that. If you have a specific recommendation on where and how exactly this should be reported to the launchpad maintenance people, then go on and answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [question](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/670587) you asked was the right place for this; it's just that we didn't manage to cope with it in time.  I've dealt with it now.